# Get refernce to child node firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have developed an admin side application from where I will be adding the email id, pin, city  and country data to the firebase realtime database. Then I will be providing the email and pin to the customer. So my simple target is that when the customer logins, the data of city and country should be displayed on his application. To do this I have to search the database for that particular customer's node which can be done through the email id which he puts during login.
I tried my best but everytime null is returned. Please have a look at my code and help me out.

```
void searchQuery(String email){

        DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("arvi-admin").orderByChild("mailId").equalTo(email);
        query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);


    }



    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {

            try {
                DataModel obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataModel.class);
                logData(""+obj.getCity());  //the values are null
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("@@","Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){


        }
    };
```

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyh2i.png)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("arvi-admin").orderByChild("mailId").equalTo(email);
```

to

```
Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.orderByChild("mailId").equalTo(email);
```

As you can see,  I have removed the call to `.child("arvi-admin")` because the root is not a child and should not be added in your reference.

**Edit:**

```
Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.orderByChild("mailId").equalTo(email);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataModel obj = ds.getValue(DataModel.class);
            Log.d(TAG, obj.getCity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: I did, this time null pointer exception is not coming but all the values are null. I have edited my question with the code through which data is being received.

Comment: The fact that all the values are null, means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question. We stick to one question at a time. Since you are new, I'll write you some code so you can get those values correctly. So please see the updated my answer.